# Data usage of anydesk

Tags: windows, windows-10, anydesk

I connected my pc to internet with LAN and my iPhone is connected to internet with WiFi. So my pc and my iPhone have been connected to same network.

Does anydesk generate Internet traffic when I connect my devices within the same network?

Comment: I've clarified wording of your question, please check if that reflects your problem

Answer (score 0):

AnyDesk is Remote Desktop software. Data is transmitted if the connection is being used by people. If no one is using the connection (for support, or whatever), then AnyDesk is not using data.

Since AnyDesk can go on multiple platforms (both of yours) you need to be careful that you are not doing anything on either platform.

Outside of AnyDesk, the devices can still use Internet and can use Internet for updates and email and things like that.

Comment: I don’t understand.this is my question: my pc and my iPhone have been connected to same internet(computer have been connected to internet with LAN to modem.Iphone have been connected to modem with wifi.) so does it use data traffic؟

Comment: Your devices can use Internet outside of AnyDesk and I amended my answer according.y.

Comment: I don’t mean outside the anydesk software.I mean that if I transfer the computer screen at home via anydesk software on the iPhone,data traffic will be consumed?

Comment: Your question is somewhat confusing, but in your last post, if you are at home transferring a screen from one device to see on another, that uses your LAN, not Internet to do that. So here again you do not have traffic going out over the Internet.